# How can I restrict my Virtual Machine using an iptables rule?

Tags: linux, iptables

I am using CentOS Linux and am planning to setup a rule on my VM's iptable.

I want to restrict all outgoing and incoming packets to the VM for a temporary period and allow only the DHCP packet to obtain an IP address (like UDP at ports 67,68). I am not sure exactly which rule to apply and how.

Does anyone know how I can do this?